# Results in Grid is not showing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I couldn't see the results in grid pane, so I did the following:

```
Tools > Options > Query Results > Results to Grid 
      > uncheck the "Discard results after execution" check box
```

But still I couldn't see the results in grid. I even hit the "Reset to Default" button in same window yet no luck

Please shed some light on this.

Comment: So what exactly happens when you run a query?

Comment: Does your query `SELECT` records at all? Or is it maybe an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: I Reset this :options > Keyboard > Reset and restarted it. now worked

Answer (score 42):

[image: Location of UI Button on Sql Server Management Studio Toolbar to change the default query output]

Check your default "Results To" selected UI element.
Make sure it is selected as "Results To Grid".

I ran into this issue and when I looked at the setting under 'Query Result' > 'SQL server' > it was already set as "Results To Grid"

I believe it was when I was trying hot-keys and fat-fingered CTRL+T which changes the results window to "Results To Text"

Answer (score 8):

Check 'General' tab under 'Query Result' > 'SQL server' to see if the 'Default destination for result' is set to 'Result to Grid'[image]

Comment: Tried that too and even restarted SSMS but still not working.

Comment: Anyway, that can be checked more easily with the menu: Query / Results To. If this was the case, I think Mar1009 would have at least said that the results were being shown as text or that he was asked to save a file.

Comment: I Reset this :options > Keyboard > Reset and restarted it. now worked

Comment: After making the update open a new query window, then the updates are working

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with this issue today in SSMS 2017, and nothing seemed to fix it.
I looked at all of the setting listed here and even reset the keyboard as mentioned by Mar1009. I would still only see the records affected. I closed SSMS, and re-opened it and it now works fine. so one of the tips above did help, not sure which one it was, but I'd just like to add that it required me shutting SSMS down and reopening it to see the fix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had accidentally flipped the `NOEXEC` flag to true which turns off execution.  In the 2019 version you can find it under `Tools > Options > Query Execution > Advanced > SET NOEXEC`.

[SET NOEXEC (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Compiles each query but does not execute it.